# How to get the matching second array of object in es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, ecmascript-5

I have two array of objects: - better solution

```
array1= [{id:1,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"nokia"},{id:3,name:"Lg"}];
array2 = [{id:5,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"panasonics"},{id:7,name:"Lg"}];
```

Expected output be:
if first array and second array id matches means take the second array name
in above example id 2 matches and we need id:2,name: panasonics.

o/p:

```
 [{id:1,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"panasonics"},{id:3,name:"Lg"},{id:5,name:"samsung"},{id:7,name:"Apple"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the arrays using `Array.concat()`, reduce them into a Map by `id`, and then convert the Map's values to an array with `Array.from()`:

```js
const unionBy = (field, ...arrays) => Array.from(
  [].concat(...arrays)
  .reduce((r, o) => r.set(o.id, o), new Map)
  .values()
);

const array1 = [{id:1,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"nokia"},{id:3,name:"Lg"}];
const array2 = [{id:5,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"panasonics"},{id:7,name:"Lg"}];

const result = unionBy('id', array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop like below (you can also use a `for` loop if you want, but `.forEach()` is easier).

This code loops through `array1`, and loops through `array2` in that loop. It then checks if the ids are the same. If there are, the name is appended to result.

```js
const array1= [{id:1,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"nokia"},{id:3,name:"Lg"}];
const array2 = [{id:5,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"panasonics"},{id:7,name:"Lg"}];
let result = [];

array1.forEach(e1 => {
  array2.forEach(e2 => {
    if (e1.id == e2.id) {
      result.push(e2.name);
    }
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map() and concat() like the following code

```
array1= [{id:1,name:"samsung"},{id:2,name:"nokia"},{id:3,name:"Lg"}];
array2 = [{id:5,name:"samsung"},  {id:2,name:"panasonics"},{id:7,name:"Lg"}];
var array3=array1.map(function(i,v){
if(array2[v].id==i.id){
return array2[v]
}
else return i
})
array4=array3.concat(array2);
console.log(array4);
```